# Why backslash means different things in Windows and the web

Tags: windows, path, ftp, directory

In FTP folders are accessed as `folder/myfolder/another`. But Windows system use `folder\myfolder\another`.

Are there any reasons for why they are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward slashes (`/`) have been used as path separators in many operating systems like any Unix variants, OS X, whereas Windows and DOS almost exclusively use the backslash (`\`).

- So this would be Windows: `C:\dir\file.txt`
- And this would be Unix: `/dir/file.txt`

There is no real advantage or disadvantage, it's just a matter of convention.

As "normal" URLs, like `ftp://example.com/file` are more or less standardized, you will never find backslashes in those.

Answer (score 4):

The history behind the path separator in Windows is detailed in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/24/432386.aspx) by Larry Osterman. FTP follows the UNIX convention.

Comment: A short summary (or relevant quote) of the linked text would enhance this (useful) answer even more.

Answer (score 1):

There's a question about where the Windows backslash (`\`) comes from at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes) with a pretty comprehensive answer.

Basically the forward slash (`/`) was used already for command options, such as

```
dir /p
```

to pause the directory listing after each page, so `\` was used as path separator instead when DOS started to support hierarchical file systems.